# How to draw gantt chart at UIView into UIViewController through objective c?

Tags: ios, charts, swift5, xcode10.3

I am new in iOS development. So please guide me step by step to drawing gantt chart.
I have seen google chart Api but not draw gantt chart.Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/evolvIQ/iqwidgets see this. It contains gnatt chart

Comment: @iAnurag" according to  iqwidgets" project, here IQGanttView .h and .m file.How to use this? Please into details.

Comment: please suggest anyone draw gantt chart without using https://github.com/evolvIQ/iqwidgets.